# Why does the `search` function doesn't run?

Tags: c, singly-linked-list, function-call

I wrote a function to search nodes in a singly linked list. When I run it, it gets stuck while printing the node does or doesn't exist. There's no warning in the code so I am wondering if there's something wrong with my concept of function calls.

I know that `curr->CharArr[9]` shouldn't be in the function call, but what should I replace with it if I don't use it? Or is it actually acceptable?

This is the function call for **searching nodes**.

```
int search(struct LLNode *curr, char* find)
{
    while (curr != NULL)
    {
        if (curr->CharArr[9] == find)
        {
            return 1;
            curr = curr->next;
        }


        else if (curr->CharArr[9] != find)
        {
            return 0;
        }
    }
}
```

This is the code which **calls it**:

```
printf("\nEnter fruit name to search in the linked list: ");
scanf("%s", find);

int result = search(curr,&find);

if (result == 1)
{
    printf("%s found in the list.\n", find);
}
else if (result == 0)
{
    printf("%s not found in the list.\n", find);
}
```

And this is the whole function:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct LLNode
{
    char *CharArr[10];
    struct LLNode *next;
};

struct LLNode * createNode (char val[])
{
    struct LLNode *temp;
    temp =(struct LLNode *)malloc(sizeof(struct LLNode));
    temp-> CharArr[9] = val;
    temp-> next = NULL;
    return (temp) ;
};

int search(struct LLNode *curr, char* find)
{
    while (curr != NULL)
    {
        if (curr->CharArr[9] == find)
        {
            return 1;
            curr = curr->next;
        }


        else if (curr->CharArr[9] != find)
        {
            return 0;
        }
    }
}


int main ()
{
    struct LLNode *head = NULL;
    struct LLNode *curr = NULL;
    char find;

    printf("The nodes are:\n");

    head = curr = createNode ("Apple") ;
    printf ("%s\n", curr->CharArr[9]) ;

    curr = curr->next;
    curr = createNode("Orange");

    printf ("%s\n", curr->CharArr[9]) ;

    printf("\nEnter fruit name to search in the linked list: ");
    scanf("%s", find);

    int result = search(curr,&find);

    if (result == 1)
    {
        printf("%s found in the list.\n", find);
    }
    else if (result == 0)
    {
        printf("%s not found in the list.\n", find);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code has a lot of problem, that make your code not work:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

struct LLNode
{
    char CharArr[10];   // problem 1: use array of char, not array of pointer of char
    struct LLNode *next;
};

struct LLNode * createNode (const char* val)
{
    struct LLNode *temp;
    temp =(struct LLNode *)malloc(sizeof(struct LLNode));
    strncpy(temp-> CharArr, val, 9); // problem 2: assign value to array
    temp->CharArr[9] = 0;            // be sure to make it null-terminated
    temp-> next = NULL;
    return (temp) ;
};

int search(struct LLNode *curr, char* find)
{
    while (curr != NULL)
    {
        if (strncmp(curr->CharArr, find, 9) == 0)   // problem 3: the way of comparing string
        {
            return 1;             // problem 4: logic of `search` function. Need follow the logic: return 1 if found. You change `cur` pointer after return is do nothing  
        }
        else
        {
            curr = curr->next;    // move to next element if not found in current node
        }
    }

    return 0;          // return 0 if not found at all
}


int main ()
{
    struct LLNode *head = NULL;
    struct LLNode *curr = NULL;
    char find[9] = {0};

    printf("The nodes are:\n");

    head = curr = createNode ("Apple") ;
    printf ("%s\n", curr->CharArr) ;

    curr->next = createNode("Orange");    // problem 5: assign wrong pointer for new element in linked list

    printf ("%s\n", curr->next->CharArr) ;

    printf("\nEnter fruit name to search in the linked list: ");
    scanf("%s", find);

    int result = search(head, find);    // problem 6: pass `head` to search, not `curr`

    if (result == 1)
    {
        printf("%s found in the list.\n", find);
    }
    else if (result == 0)
    {
        printf("%s not found in the list.\n", find);
    }

}
```

The above code is sample of fix

Comment: Can I know why `strncmp(curr->CharArr, find, 9) ` only runs when `== 0` but not `== 1`? I thought 0 stands for false (which means doesn't exist).

Comment: `==0` mean equal. Refer to http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strncmp/

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, the struct should be like this.

```
struct LLNode
{
    char *CharArr;
    struct LLNode *next;
};
```

The `search` function needs to use `strcmp` to match string and you should only return when a match is found.

```
int search(struct LLNode *curr, char* find)
{
    while (curr != NULL)
    {
        if (strcmp(curr->CharArr, find) == 0)
            return 1;
        curr = curr->next;
    }
    return 0; 
}
```

And in your main function, you need to pass in `head` to the `search` function. `curr` points to the latest node you inserted. And `curr->next` needs to be allocated first to have it be part of the linked list.

```
    curr->next = createNode("Orange");
    curr = curr->next;

    printf ("%s\n", curr->CharArr) ;

    printf("\nEnter fruit name to search in the linked list: ");
    scanf("%s", find);

    int result = search(head, find);
```

Comment: What if I want to let the `struct` definition includes a character array of size 10 (to store a string)? Is that possible?

Comment: @lyhsuan01 Change it to `char CharArr[10]` and then use `strcpy` when you assign to it in `createNode`